# ¿Cómo determinar la ruta anterior en Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

Necesito obtener la url desde la que se abre un componente para hacer una validación, ejemplo. Al entrar a la ruta `/unaRuta` necesito obtener la ruta desde la que se abrió. Para esto estoy intentado la solución a [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular):

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Importo los observables y el método filter de RXJS

```
urlAnterior: string;
```

Declaro una variable

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
  router.events.filter( event => event instanceof NavigationEnd ).subscribe( (e) => {
    console.log('Anterior: ', this.urlAnterior);
    this.urlAnterior = e.url;
  });
}
```

Dentro de mi constructor utilizo el método `filter` y me subscribo al resultado. Pero la consola me da un error:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/X.component.ts(43,23): error TS2339: Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable<Event>'.
```

También encontré esta respuesta, pero no obtengo la ruta anterior.

```
constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
ngOnInit() {
  this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  ).subscribe(() => {
  console.log(this.activatedRoute.root);
  });
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41038970/how-to-determine-previous-page-url-in-angular revisa esta respuesta, esta en ingles

Comment: Ya intentaste usando el operador *pipe*?... No estoy muy seguro, pero posiblemente se deba a las versiones de angular que estás manejando: router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe( (e) => {
      console.log('Anterior: ', this.urlAnterior);
      this.urlAnterior = e.url;
    }))

Answer (score 2):

El problema que pareces tener es debido a [cómo ha evolucionado la librería RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/91088dae1df097be2370c73300ffa11b27fd0100/doc/pipeable-operators.md). Esta librería es usada por Angular desde sus inicios, pero conforme nuevas versiones de Angular eran publicadas, las dependencias de éste sobre RxJS fueron también variando, provocando que el código no fuese retrocompatible:

Hemos pasado de:

```
observable.map(...).filter(...).subscribe(...);
```

a

```
observable.pipe(map(....),filter(...)).subscribe.
```

Por tanto, los antiguos métodos de observable han pasado a ser operadores que se importan de manera independiente:

```
import { map, filter, scan } from 'rxjs/operators';
```